# Select more than one row with same value in one column in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a comment system using PHP and MySQL. I have made a table named "comment" which stores the details

```
id  | date      |product_id | user_name | email_id          | comment
    |           |           |           |                   |
1   |2013-05-07 |  10001    |  jabong   | jabong@jabong.com | this is good product
2   |2013-05-07 |  10001    |  john     | john@gmail.com    | I bought this product
```

and so on

---

Now I want to select and print all those rows which have product_id=10001.
I'm using the following code to print the details

```
  $comment="";
  $id=$_GET['id'];//this is the product_id which is taken from URL
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE product_id='$id'");
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $name = $data["user_name"];
        $email = $data["email_id"];
        $comment = $data["comment"];
        $date=strftime("%d %b, %Y", strtotime($data["date"]));

        $comment.='<table>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Date: '.$date.'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Name: '.$name.'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Email_id: '.$email.'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Product Review: '.$comment.'</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table><hr />';
```

and then I'm echoing them in the body section. but I'm getting only one result. 
so please help me to get the right code.

Comment: Why using `$comment` variable multiple time , it must be getting overwrite. Try giving different variable name.

Comment: Have you tried your sql request in phpMyAdmin for example... you have several results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this line:

```
$comment = $data["comment"];
```

that's overwriting this one:

```
$comment.='<table>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Date: '.$date.'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Name: '.$name.'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Email_id: '.$email.'</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>Product Review: '.$comment.'</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table><hr />';
```

so when you're making the `echo $comment` it's displaying the last one.

Change the variable and DONE

something like:

```
 $comment_sql = $data["comment"];
....
    $comment.='<table>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Date: '.$date.'</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Name: '.$name.'</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Email_id: '.$email.'</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>Product Review: '.$comment_sql.'</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table><hr />'; 
...
```

Comment: i corrected my script as according to you. but it didn't solve the problem. I'm getting only one record from select statement.

Comment: ohh thanks everybody !! its done !!
i was not using concatenation symbol after making changes to varaiables !! now its done !!

Answer (score 1):

There was a small problem with my code. I was using the same variable twice and also i didn't use the concatenate symbol. But now it is solved---

```
      $review="";
      if (isset($_GET['id']))
  {
      $id=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['id']));
      $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE product_id='$id'");
      $review.='<table width="70%" cellpadding="6px" cellspacing="0" >';
      while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $name = $data["user_name"];
            $email = $data["email_id"];
            $comment = $data["comment"];
            $date=strftime("%d %b, %Y", strtotime($data["date"]));
            $review.='<tr>
                        <td>
                          <table width="100%" border="0" style="border:1px solid; border-color:#05fdee; background-color:#e4f2f1;">
                              <tr>
                                <td rowspan="2" width="100px"> <img src="profile.png" /> </td>
                                <td align="left"><b> '.$name.' </b> says -</td>
                                <td align="right"><b> '.$date.' </b></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">'.$comment.'</td>
                              </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>';

        }// while loop ends here
        $review.='</table>'; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First most important thing, clean your data.

```
$id=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['id']));
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE product_id='$id'");
```

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))

The second problem is you are overwriting the variable $comment in each loop, so you are only getting 1 record, even though you are looping twice.

```
remove this: $comment = $data["comment"];
change this: <td>Product Review: '.$comment.'</td>
to this: <td>Product Review: '.$data["comment"].'</td>
```

Comment: thanks to all of you for ur suggestions. I did exactly what you said here. but couldn't get the solution. I'm getting only one record printed. I don't know what's going on ?